# Passing data between long running threads (LocalBroadcastManager deprecated)

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following scenario: a foreground service spawns 2 HandlerThreads (A and B). From time to time A must send some data to B, B performs a certain action on this data and sends back to A the result of the operation. I do not know how to effectivelly pass data between these 2 threads. Originally I was posting messages to the MainService thread (via handlers), which in turn posted it to the appropriate thread. But it seems like a bit overkill:

- (thread A) post message to main thread handler
- (main thread) receive the message and post it to the thread B handler
- (thread B) do something and post the result back to the main thread handler
- (main thread) receive the message and post it to the thread A handler
- (thread A) do something

I thought that I could use LocalBroadcastManager, but it seems to be deprecated now. Do you have any suggestion on that?

### EDIT 1

Simplified version of the program. I am afraid that the showed code will get too much complex after adding more signals between threads.

`MainService.java`

```java
public class MainService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MainService";
    public static final Integer START_A = 0;
    public static final Integer DO_STH_IN_B = 1;
    public static final Integer RESPOND_FROM_B_TO_A = 2;

    private Handler mServiceHandler  = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        // this is a dispatcher for messages between threads
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            Message msg_s;

            if (msg.what == DO_STH_IN_B)
                msg_s = Message.obtain(myThreadB.getHandler());
            else if (msg.what == RESPOND_FROM_B_TO_A)
                msg_s = Message.obtain(myThreadA.getHandler());
            else return;

            msg_s.what = msg.what;
            msg_s.sendToTarget();
        }
    };

    private MyThreadA myThreadA = new MyThreadA(mServiceHandler);
    private MyThreadB myThreadB = new MyThreadB(mServiceHandler);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myThreadA.start();
        myThreadB.start();
        SystemClock.sleep(100);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "M_ID")
                        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                        .setContentText("Notification Text")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        Message msg = Message.obtain(myThreadA.getHandler());
        msg.what = START_A;
        msg.sendToTarget();
        //stopSelf();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myThreadA.quit();
        myThreadB.quit();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`MyThreadA.java`

```java
public class MyThreadA extends HandlerThread {
    private static final String TAG = "MyThreadA";
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Handler mMainServiceHandler;

    public MyThreadA(Handler handler) {
        super(TAG, Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        mMainServiceHandler = handler;
    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == MainService.START_A) {
                    mHandler.post(myRoutine);
                } else if (msg.what == MainService.RESPOND_FROM_B_TO_A) {
                    mHandler.post(myRoutineRespond);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public Handler getHandler() { return mHandler; }

    private Runnable myRoutine = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: [thread A] myRoutine");
            // do something here (may be blocking)
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);

            // send message to Thread B (by passing it through the main service)
            Message msg = Message.obtain(mMainServiceHandler);
            msg.what = MainService.DO_STH_IN_B;
            msg.sendToTarget();

            // repeat the routine
            mHandler.post(myRoutine);
        }
    };

    private Runnable myRoutineRespond = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: [thread A] respond handler");
            // do something here with the respond from B
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        }
    };
}
```

`MyThreadB.java`

```java
public class MyThreadB extends HandlerThread {
    private static final String TAG = "MyThreadB";
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Handler mMainServiceHandler;

    public MyThreadB(Handler handler) {
        super(TAG, Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        mMainServiceHandler = handler;
    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == MainService.DO_STH_IN_B) {
                    mHandler.post(myRoutine);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public Handler getHandler() { return mHandler; }

    private Runnable myRoutine = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: [thread B] do something and respond");
            // do something here (may be blocking)
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);

            // send respond back to Thread A
            Message msg = Message.obtain(mMainServiceHandler);
            msg.what = MainService.RESPOND_FROM_B_TO_A;
            msg.sendToTarget();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the relevant sections of your code? Also, what kind of data are you trying to transfer and are you storing it anywhere?

Comment: @SammyT I added simplified version of the code, please take a look.